# Why in this program BufferedReader taking infinite input

Tags: java-8, bufferedreader

Why is in this program `BufferedReader` taking infinite input?

Below is the code which is taking  input infinitely. To avoid this I have added condition

```
    while((!(s1=br.readLine().trim()).equals(null))&&(!s1.isEmpty())){
```

but it didn't  work out.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class skylerStudent {
public static void main(String []args)throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s1="";String s="";
    while((!(s1=br.readLine().trim()).equals(null))&&(!s1.isEmpty())){
        s+=s1.trim()+" ";   

    }
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s.trim());
    int i=0,n=0,q=0;
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        if(i==0)n=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        if(i==1)q=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

        i++;
    }
    int ar[]=new int[n];i=0;
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    if(i<n)ar[i]=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        StringTokenizer st1=new StringTokenizer(st.nextToken());

        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            if(i<q){
    int a=Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken());
    int b=Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken());
    System.out.println(a);System.out.println(b);}
    i++;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. Just enter an empty line, and the loop stops. Nothing can ever .equals(null), so the first part of the confition doesn't make sense. For  something.equals(null) to be true, something would have to be null, but then the callto .equals() would throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: This looks like a job for [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Scanner.html)…

Answer (score 0):

The condition `!(s1 = br.readLine().trim()).equals(null)` is not correct. If you can call .trim on string then it can never be null. You can check

```
(s1 = br.readLine()) != null
```

Also the infinite loop is not in the reading the input, its in the one of the later loops of the code.

```
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            if (i == 0)
                n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            if (i == 1)
                q = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

            i++;
        }
```

You are not moving forward to `nextToken()` if the i is not in (0,1). That's why it would never exit the loop.

Comment: Oh... I got this.. Thanks.